# Predefined SVG paths for character forms

Tags: svg, path, typefaces, character

In order to avoid to align more than 100 circles manually I'd like to automatically align them on a path which has the form of a character. Can I find predefined paths somewhere for those characters?  Paths would be different for all sorts of fonts, so I'm looking for a well known one or a generic way to produce the paths from an arbitrary font.

EDIT: I'd like to write my SVG in a text editor.

Comment: What tool(s) are you using to attempt this?

Comment: If you're looking for monoline character definitions, try the Hershey Fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I've often created vector art (using Chinese characters) in Illustrator, and then "saved it as a SVG" to copy and paste that SVG code into an HTML document.

Perhaps you could type the text that you want to use in Illustrator, convert the text to paths, distribute the circles along those paths, and then export it as an SVG. You can copy and paste the auto-generated code, which is easy to edit (if you want to add ID's, classes, onclick's, etc to the various elements in the SVG).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inkscape: write some text (note: use normal text created by single-clicking with the text tool, not flowed text created by dragging), then use the "Convert to Path" command. This will create a group with each letter represented by a separate path. You can use the Ungroup and Combine commands to join letters into a single path. Save in the "Plain SVG" format to avoid writing out extra editing information and then modify the file in a text editor.

I'm not sure what you mean by aligning circles on a path, but you can use markers or the "Pattern along Path" path effect to put shapes on the path.